# Import a specific element with c:import in a .jsp

Tags: java, jsp, xpath, import, jstl

I want to import a specific element from an external xhtml file into my JSP. Is this possible with the  JSTL libraries?

**background**

We have a XHTML help page. Each help topic is in a `div` element and each `div` has an `id`. In other parts of our application we want to import specific `id`s from the help page to provide context specific assistance.

We've been experimenting with

```
<c:import var="helpData" url="file:/tmp/help.html"/>
<x:parse var="helpXml" doc="${helpData}  " />
<x:out select="$helpXml//div[@id='helpTopicXXX']" escapeXml="false"/>
```

however we have two problems

1. `parse` is really slow (~10 seconds) on XHTML (changing the first line to `<?xml...` from `<!DOCTYPE...` fixes this.)
2. Any markup within the chosen element disappear. Example `I <b>love</b> tacos` comes out as `I love tacos`

Does anyone have a good way of displaying a specific element from an external source? Does anyone know how to get the JSTL xml library to display the chosen node as xml rather than text (to fix problem 2)?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this in a JSP.

Comment: @DaveNewton I wouldn't consider the 'help content' part of the model. I would consider it part of the view. As to why do it server side vs using JavaScript to load it on demand - we think it is easier to meet our accessibility goals (screen readers for example) if the help content doesn't need to be loaded with AJAX. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: IMO doing this kind of logic in the view runs counter to what JSPs are for; the view layer should be as dumb as possible. It's also more difficult to test this way. Anything that makes it to the view layer *is* part of the model, whether it's exposed via the context, an "official" model object, etc. Of course, I also think keeping it in a giant HTML file isn't awesome either. YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the feedback. This is really a big experiment. Our milage may easily be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use JSoup and a custom tag to do this.
Our proof of concept is

WEB-INF/tags/htmlParser.tag

```
<%@ attribute description = "The html data to parse." name="html" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@ attribute description = "The id to grab from the html." name="id" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%
 org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html);
 org.jsoup.nodes.Element e = doc.select("#" + id).first();
 if (e != null) {
    out.println(e.outerHtml());
 } else {
getJspBody().invoke(out);
 }
%>
```

and a sample .jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="h" %>
<head></head>
<body>
<c:import var="helpData" url="file:/tmp/help.html"/>

<p>Help loaded from other file:</p>
<h:htmlParser html="${helpData}" id="helpTopic1"/>

<p>Example loading invalid id</p>
<h:htmlParser html="${helpData}" id="taco">
Display this text if id <i>taco</i> doesn't exist.
</h:htmlParser>

</body>
```